# jquery - get the value of <tr> in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a AJAX created table.

And I need to call a ajax request on the those table which was created through ajax.

Through [**this**](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) I figured out to call the click function on dynamically created HTML element.

Table looks similar like this.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>Label</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr value="1">
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr value="2">
            <td>2.</td>
            <td>Two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've assigned value to the `tr` and now I want to create another ajax request on click of the `tr`. And based on the value I'm running a query to get the data.

Challenge I'm facing is that I'm not able to get the value of the `tr`.

Here's the code I tried with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() {
        alert($(this).val())
    })
})
```

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tqQm5/).

Even in the fiddle I'm unable to get the value of a `tr`.

Please help me to find where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('value'))
    })
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqQm5/1/)**

but actually you should use `data-*` HTML5 attribute:

```
<tr data-value="1">
```

then retrieve it using `.data()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() {
        alert($(this).data('value'))
    })
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqQm5/2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll change it right away. What's the difference in using `data-value` and `value` by the way? And why wasn't I able to get the data when I was using `val()`?

Comment: `value` is invalid HTML attribute for `tr` elements. That's why you need to use `data-value`. The data-* attributes allow you to embed custom data attributes on all HTML elements which is consider as _valid_

Comment: I did go through [**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). So, it is better to use `data-*` in all my case where I'm about pass on my private data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this use`.attr()`

```
alert($(this).attr("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    })
})
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/tqQm5/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use text() property of tr instated of val() property.

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqQm5/6/)

see this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').on('click', 'table tbody tr', function() {
       alert($(this).text())
    })
})
```